# How to access JSON object in React where the keys change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, alpha-vantage

I'm having a hard time with my React app. I'm calling the AlphaVantage API to get RSI data. I'm wanting to get the most recent RSI value like this:

```
    const cryptos = ['AAPL', 'MSFT']
    const arr = []
    for (var i = 0; i < cryptos.length; i++) {
      const cryptoUrl =
        'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=RSI&symbol=' +
        cryptos[i] +
        `&interval=weekly&time_period=10&series_type=open&apikey=${apikey}`
      arr.push(axios.get(cryptoUrl))
    }

    Promise.all(arr)
      .then(response =>
        response.map(res =>
          console.log(
            res.data['Technical Analysis: RSI']['2019-08-30'][' RSI'],
            res.data['Meta Data']['1: Symbol']
          )
        )
      )
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
```

Everything is working great, with the exception of

```
res.data['Technical Analysis: RSI']['2019-08-30'][' RSI'],
```

I'm trying to access the latest RSI value, however, the latest value has a time on it that's always changing. I don't know how to get it.

The JSON looks like this:
[image]

Notice on line 15 of the screenshot the 'format' of the key changes to include both date and time.

Thanks and please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: As mentioned by @NarendraJadhav notice that your code has a space `[' RSI']` whereas the value in the JSON does not. Could this be the reason it's not working at that line?

Comment: `console.log(Object.entries(res.data['Technical Analysis: RSI']).map(([key,value])=>value))`

Comment: Try to talk with the backend team to send it in a more readable and convenient way Or you should have to do some workaround to get it done, have to write unnecessary code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also pass the `Last Refreshed` property, that the API returns, as the 'date' attribute.. This way you always get the most recent update and don't have to fiddle with indexes or converting things to date objects.

You'll need to supply your API key, but I threw this together and it works..( it actually looks like this works with '123' as the API key =/ )

https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/JjPMVmy?editors=1010

```
let lastRefresh = res.data["Meta Data"]["3: Last Refreshed"];
let stockInfo = {
  symbol: res.data["Meta Data"]["1: Symbol"],
  price: res.data["Technical Analysis: RSI"][lastRefresh]["RSI"]
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much Matt, really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

That's honestly a poor API design to mix formats.

Luckily though, both of those formats can be parsed by simply passing it as a parameter to `new Date()`.

```
new Date('2019-08-30')
new Date('2019-09-06 15:21:38')
```

Once converted to `Date` objects, you can simply use the `<` and `>` symbols to compare them to figure out which is the newest.

To get the newest, you can use `Object.keys()` to see all of the values, compare them, then pick the newest. In the below example, I use `reduce()` to find the newest.

```js
const data = {
  'Technical Analysis: RSI': {
    '2019-08-01 16:00:00': {
      a: 1
    },
    '2019-09-01': {
      b: 1
    },
    '2019-08-15': {
      c: 1
    }
  }
};

const newest = Object.keys(data['Technical Analysis: RSI'])
  .reduce((newest, time) => new Date(time) > new Date(newest) ? time : newest, '1980-01-01'); // '1980-01-01' is just an old default value to start with.
  
console.log(newest, data['Technical Analysis: RSI'][newest]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I'll give this a go as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since the keys are ordered, you can access them with `Object.keys(yourJSON).reduce` and find the newest value.

Extract that value and return it. This should let you access the newest value.

Comment: Assuming the keys are ordered without the API explicitly stating that will always be the case is actually very dangerous. It would be best to actual evaluate the date unless you have such a guarantee.

Comment: That what I meant with using reduce to find the newest value :) but your answer elaborates that.

Answer (score 0):

If the latest value has a time attached to it (as in, it includes both a date and time) while the other values don't, you could always grab the value attached to the object with the timestamp via regex.

For example:

```
let data;
for(let key in res.data['Technical Analysis: RSI']) {
  if(key.match(/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/)
    data = res.data['Technical Analysis: RSI'][key]['RSI'];
    break;
}
```

Alternatively, you could match the ":" character since it only seems to appear when time is present.